# Spring WS - jaxb2 marshaller IBM Portal LinkageError

Tags: xml, web-services, jaxb, spring-ws

In my project I'm using:

- Spring 4.2.4
- Spring-WS 2.2.4
- Axiom 1.2.15

More details on my project: I'm building a portlet; I'm developing a standard JSR-286 Portlet by using Spring and using Liferay as portal system for development

At the end this portlet will run on IBM Websphere portal version 8; in this case all works pretty good except web service consume

When, on IBM, I try to consume the Web Service (same web service and same endpoint used for the development) I get the following error:

```
2016-01-14 12:54:03,379 10699 [WebContainer : 0] ERROR o.s.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet - Could not complete request
javax.portlet.PortletException: Error occured during request processing: javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doResourceService(DispatcherPortlet.java:896) ~[spring-webmvc-portlet-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.processRequest(FrameworkPortlet.java:540) [spring-webmvc-portlet-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.FrameworkPortlet.serveResource(FrameworkPortlet.java:490) [spring-webmvc-portlet-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:153) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.el.init.AttributeCopyFilter.doFilter(AttributeCopyFilter.java:185) [wp.jsp.el.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:146) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.iwidget.filter.IWidgetPortletFilter.doFilter(IWidgetPortletFilter.java:81) [wp.resolver.iwidget.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:146) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.plm.GlobalPortletLoadMonitoringFilter.doFilter(GlobalPortletLoadMonitoringFilter.java:182) [wp.pe.plm.jar:[wp800.base] wp800_404_01]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:146) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.filter.impl.GlobalPortletFilter.doFilter(GlobalPortletFilter.java:192) [wp.pe.rt.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:146) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.pcm.scoping.filter.PCMScopingFilter.doFilter(PCMScopingFilter.java:114) [wp.pcm.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletFilterChainImpl.doFilter(PortletFilterChainImpl.java:146) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:545) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:332) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60) [com.ibm.wsspi.rrd.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaboratorImpl.java:121) [wp.pe.rt.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:79) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1385) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:194) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:213) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaboratorServeResource(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:98) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:54) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doServeResource(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:75) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaboratorServeResource(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:92) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:54) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doServeResource(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:349) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaboratorServeResource(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:92) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:54) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.serveResource(PortletInvokerImpl.java:136) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doServeResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:447) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ResourcePortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(ResourcePortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:62) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doServeResource(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:101) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ResourcePortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(ResourcePortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:53) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.servePortletResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:418) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$4.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:185) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:327) [na:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeServeResource(PortletInvokerImpl.java:181) [com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl$2.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:107) [wp.pe.rt.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:182) [wp.pe.rt.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.core.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeServeResource(PortletInvokerImpl.java:104) [wp.pe.rt.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.waspc.PortletContainerImpl.servePortletResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:201) [wp.pe.rt.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.pe.pc.PortletContainerImpl.servePortletResource(PortletContainerImpl.java:137) [wp.pe.rt.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.extension.render.ResourceServingRenderer.render(ResourceServingRenderer.java:128) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.extension.render.ResourceServingRenderer.render(ResourceServingRenderer.java:85) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPResourceRenderPhase.processRendering(WPResourceRenderPhase.java:162) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPResourceRenderPhase.processRendering(WPResourceRenderPhase.java:108) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPBaseRenderPhase.execute(WPBaseRenderPhase.java:250) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractRenderPhase.next(AbstractRenderPhase.java:106) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPAbstractRenderPhase.next(WPAbstractRenderPhase.java:100) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPResourceRenderPhase.next(WPResourceRenderPhase.java:242) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:315) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:686) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:411) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:780) [wp.resolver.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:96) [wp.resolver.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1388) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter$ExtendedFilterChain.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:110) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:197) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.SupportedLocalesFilter.doFilter(SupportedLocalesFilter.java:113) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191) [wp.resolver.friendly.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilterWithoutProjectID(ProjectIdFilter.java:405) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilter(ProjectIdFilter.java:319) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.doFilter(PreviewFilterImpl.java:351) [wp.auth.cmd.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.doFilter(PreviewFilterImpl.java:351) [wp.auth.cmd.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:443) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:89) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerGzip.internalDoFilter(ContentHandlerGzip.java:704) [wp.resolver.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerGzip.doFilter(ContentHandlerGzip.java:451) [wp.resolver.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:96) [wp.resolver.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:103) [wp.engine.impl.jar:[wp8001.base] wp8001CF12_001_15]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3837) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200) [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:88) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864) [com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshalStaxSource(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:793) ~[spring-oxm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:766) ~[spring-oxm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.support.MarshallingUtils.unmarshal(MarshallingUtils.java:62) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate$3.extractData(WebServiceTemplate.java:413) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:619) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:2.2.4.RELEASE]
    at it.eng.tz.cdm.turismo.fase2.spring.ws.client.CrmCatalogueWsClientImpl.getCrmCategories(CrmCatalogueWsClientImpl.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.eng.tz.cdm.turismo.fase2.servizi.shared.service.impl.SharedPorletCfgSvcImpl.getCategorieCrm(SharedPorletCfgSvcImpl.java:106) ~[classes/:na]
    at it.eng.tz.cdm.turismo.fase2.servizi.segnalazione.attivita.web.controller.ConfigurazioneSegnalazioneAttivitaCtrl.getCategorieCrm(ConfigurazioneSegnalazioneAttivitaCtrl.java:75) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) ~[na:1.6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:178) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:369) ~[spring-webmvc-portlet-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.doHandle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:356) ~[spring-webmvc-portlet-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handleResource(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:302) ~[spring-webmvc-portlet-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.portlet.DispatcherPortlet.doResourceService(DispatcherPortlet.java:855) ~[spring-webmvc-portlet-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 140 common frames omitted
```

I can't solve this issue... It seems something related to Jaxb and Jaxb version but I tried to generate WS clients (from the WSDL) by specifying jaxb 2.0, jabx 2.1 and jaxb 2.2; under liferay (and with a junit test) all works good; under IBM Portal I have the showed error...

On IBM server the java -version command gives to me the following result:

```
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6460_26sr7fp1ifix-20140220_01(SR7 FP1+IX90136+IX90137))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.6.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20131230_180580 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java626_SR7_20131230_1725_B180580
JIT  - r11.b05_20131003_47443.02
GC   - R26_Java626_SR7_20131230_1725_B180580_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20131230_180580)
JCL  - 20140107_01
```

Any ideas about how i can solve the issue?

thank you
Angelo

Answer (score 0):

finally I was able in solving my issue; the issue was related to the stax implementation
In my WS client I use axiom; axiom ships with a sTax implementation; this means that under my portlet, in WEB-INF/lib I had a stax2 jar; once in my pom i excluded this jar, all worked correctly

I hope this can help somebody